# Why is the direct pronoun NOT attached to the infinitive in "Vendería mi camioneta pero nadie la quiere comprar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, pronombres

In the following sentence why is the direct pronoun "la" **not** attached to the end of the infinitive "comprar"?

> Vendería mi camioneta pero nadie la quiere comprar. (found on the SpanishDict site)

Comment: I do believe it is correct either way, "nadie quiere comprarla" or "nadie la queire comprar".

Comment: That's why Spanish is hard because there are some real hard ones. In general, direct objects can go before the first verb or be attached to the second.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [this site](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Pronombres%20%C3%A1tonos%20-%20colocaci%C3%B3n.htm), in verb phrases (VP) including infinitive or gerund the pronoun can (save for a few exceptions) appear before the VP or be added to the nonfinite:

- **La** quiero comprar = Quiero comprar**la**.
- **La** voy a comprar = Voy a comprar**la**.
- **La** estoy comprando = Estoy comprándo**la**.

Comment: We say infinitive, not nonfinite.

Comment: @Lambie Nonfinites include infinitives, gerunds and participles. I thus made reference to both infinitives and gerunds.

Comment: I don't think most learners would know that word.

Comment: @Lambie Now they know.

Comment: Although most people wouldn't go that far, I should note that while nonfinites include participles, pronouns cannot be cliticized to participles (*He comprado* ~ *He \*comprádola*). I get that by naming "infinitive or gerund" before, you're limiting the scope, but still.

Comment: @pablodf76 I just used "nonfinite" to avoid repeating "infinitive or gerund". In the context, "**the** nonfinite" clearly refers to those two types of nonfinites mentioned earlier in the sentence. "nonfinite" would be, as you well know, "forma no conjugada".

Comment: I think it might be clearer to say the nonfinite term (or form) for those of us not familiar with its usage in grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is correct to say: Vendería mi camioneta pero nadie quiere comprarla. In the example you gave, the direct pronoun is before "quiere"

Comment: quiere is not a direct object. It is a verb.

Comment: @walen actually this answer is previous, if you check the times.